# Correct php code for EE3

Tags: ee3, date-format, low-yearly-archives

Im trying to set up this php code in EE3

```
<?php
$year = $this->EE->localize->format_date("%Y", $this->EE->localize->now);
?>
```

How would I write it to be EE3 compatible?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $year = ee()->localize->format_date('%Y'); ?>
```

would output the same as the standard EE tag

```
{current_time format="%Y"}
```

for more information, please view the localize class documentation here:
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/legacy/libraries/localization.html